# How to fire Click event on Angular Web Component (Custom Element) from a simple html page using javascript

Tags: angular, custom-element

I have created an Angular Web Component like below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dlx-comp',
  templateUrl: './comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
})
export class CompComponent implements OnInit {

  onClick() {
    console.log('alert click');
  }

}
```

and template is very simple

```
<button (click)="onClick()"></button>
```

and in my app module

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.defineElement(compComponent, 'dlx-comp');
  }

  private defineElement(component: any, elementName: string) {
    const el = createCustomElement(component, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define(elementName, el);

  }
}
```

everything is working fine and I have embedded it in a simple HTML page like below

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TMIBot</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Test Angular Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://urltomy/dist/dlx-styles-1.0.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="button">Open comp </button>
    <dlx-comp id="comp"></dlx-comp>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://urltomy/dist/dlx-chatbot-1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector('#button');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const comp = document.querySelector('#comp');
            comp.click();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to call the `click` method on it. but it doesn't do anything, no errors in console, also I checked `comp` has value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are defining `(click)` on `button` inside `dlx-comp`, and you are trying to fire `click` event on `dlx-comp` you should find that button inside `dlx-comp` and on it fire `click`

```
   button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const comp = document.querySelector('#comp');
        const btn = comp.querySelector('dlx-comp::shadow button');
        btn.click();
    });
```

Comment: thanks for answer, the `btn` is `null`, could `shadow-dom` affects on query selector

Comment: I found the element by `comp.querySelector('* /deep/ button')` still click is not working

Comment: I think `/deep/` has been removed or it's deprecated so you shoulnd't use it at all, but check if button inside component exists

Comment: Sorry my mistake I was getting another button there, now it's working, 
either using `deep` or `comp.querySelector("dlx-comp::shadow button.main-button");` both are working
a

Comment: I update your answer in case somebody else has same issue